# Getting "jobs -l" to show actual command, without unexpanded variables

Tags: bash, shell

I executed a background process that was obtained as a parameter and didn't success to get the process's name after the execution.

I do the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

filePath=$1
$filePath > log.txt &
echo `jobs -l`
```

Actual result:

```
[1]+ 2381 Running $filePath > log.txt &
```

Expected result:

```
[1]+ 2381 Running /home/user/Desktop/script.sh > log.txt &
```

Comment: BTW, note that for a shebang to have any effect, it needs to be `#!/bin/bash`, not `!#/bin/bash`.

Comment: BTW, why the `echo` at all? `jobs -l` itself writes its output to stdout, so capturing it and then writing it again looks pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer is **don't**; job control is a feature designed for interactive use, and is not guaranteed to be available at all in noninteractive shells, much less guaranteed to behave in any useful or meaningful way. However, if you insist, you can use `printf %q` to generate an `eval`-safe string with the post-expansion form of your variables, and then use `eval` to run it as code:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v logfile_q '%q' "${log:-log.txt}"  # use "$logfile", or default to log.txt
printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "$@"                  # quote our arguments into one eval-safe string

eval "$cmd_str >$logfile_q &"  # Parts that aren't hardcoded must be printf-q'd for safety.
jobs -l
```

Note that I added some extra configurability for the sake of demonstration -- it's okay to have `>log.txt` inside your `eval`'d code, but it's *not* safe to have `>$logfile`, because if `logfile=$'foo$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` (a perfectly legal filename!) then you're going to lose your home directory. Thus, *any* variables needing to be used inside an argument to `eval` need to be escaped with `printf %q` beforehand.

Comment: If you don't use `printf %q` to create its argument, using `eval` runs major security risks. See [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)